# How can I match files by extension when they have other dots in their filenames?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a `RewriteRule` that will match files by their extension, and what I've come up with is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^.]*\.less)$ ./index.php?f=$1
</IfModule>
```

This works fine when the only dot in the filename is the one separating the extension, but fails when there are other dots in there. For example, it won't work for `hello.world.less`.

I have no clue on how to proceed from here, any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just removing that character class and just use `.` instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.less)$ ./index.php?f=$1
```

This will match any file name that ends with `.less` regardless of what other characters come before it.

Comment: 1 min 40 seconds for a correct answer, that's ridiculously awesome! Thanks! Unfortunately, I cannot upvote yet (not enough reputation), but I can at least accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
^(.*\.less)$
```

This still enforces the last dot to exist.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I cannot upvote yet (not enough reputation), and the other answer appeared first so I decided to accept that one. Sorry about that, will come back to upvote when I get enough reputation.

Comment: @user2590712 Don't worry, +1 on your behalf.